# Android: Unfortunately (project name) has stopped working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

•   An area which will present a predefined question
•   A button which will cause the answer to the question to be shown while leaving the question on the screen
•   An area which will present the answer
•   A button which will cause a transition to a screen that is formatted the same as this one, with the next question shown on it
•   A button which will cause the app to end (a transition to (3))

What I am trying to accomplish and I get the error when I run the program, I will provide logcat.  I am new to android programming so it is probably a silly mistake somewhere.

The only thing that is supposed to work is change from 1 question to the next by button press, nothing more.  Only 2/5 done.

```
    10-30 14:20:27.646: D/AndroidRuntime(769): Shutting down VM
10-30 14:20:27.646: W/dalvikvm(769): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidassignment2/com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Textview
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Textview
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  ... 11 more
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Textview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.androidassignment2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.androidassignment2-1, /system/lib]]
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  ... 21 more
10-30 14:20:32.196: I/Process(769): Sending signal. PID: 769 SIG: 9
```

Screen 1

```
package com.example.androidassignment2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AndroidAssignment2_1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



 }
```

screen 2

```
package com.example.androidassignment2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AndroidAssignment2_1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_assignment2_1);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_assignment2_1, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml for 1 and 2 identical for most part.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Textview android:id="@+id/Questions"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:text="@string/Q1"   />

<Button android:id="@+id/QButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_question" />

<Button android:id="@+id/AButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<Textview android:id="@+id/Answers"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:hint="@string/A1" />

<Button android:id="@+id/QuitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_quit" />


</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Textview android:id="@+id/Questions"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:text="@string/Q2"   />

<Button android:id="@+id/QButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_question"  />

<Button android:id="@+id/AButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<Textview android:id="@+id/Answers"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:hint="@string/A2" />

<Button android:id="@+id/QuitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_quit" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<Textview android:id="@+id/Questions"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:text="@string/Q1"   />
```

to

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/Questions"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:text="@string/Q1"   />
```

note the spelling of `TextView`

The last part of the following line says that it can't inflate a class `Textview` and we know the reason is because that is not the actual spelling of the class

```
10-30 14:20:27.706: E/AndroidRuntime(769): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.example.androidassignment2/com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Textview    / this part here
```

Change all of your `TextView`s to the proper spelling.

Comment: Why would you downvote the correct answer which also has a good explanation?

Comment: seriously, i am too thinking that ... ! although let's balance that !

Comment: Thanks @twntee but I wish people would leave explanations. The worst part about it is for future visitors to see the downvote and, not knowing any better, think there is something wrong with the answer and confuse them even more.

Comment: of course ! but as you know, people trying to down vote others, so as their answers get to top, accepted for reps !

Comment: +1 from me to to help restore the natural balance of the Androidverse (and because it is a good, correct answer).  I've had one of my top answers suddenly downvoted with no comment.  It's a perfect answer too.  Freekin annoying.  I don't care about the 2 points but I do care about muppetry.

Comment: Because you shoot from the hip. When I downvoted the answer, it was incomplete, ending at "`TextView`" -- you had missed four additional places where it was misspelled. An answer of the form "try this.... <code>" is not an answer; it won't help the asker and has no value to future readers. Give the **reason** for the error, then a solution, even if it means you won't be the first to post your response. @Henry's answer was of better quality, and it was complete, even though it is shorter.

Comment: @Simon agreed! I got to the rep point I wanted to long ago but its about keeping the site clean so it can maintain the respect and effectiveness it currently has for all developers.

Comment: @323go Thank you for the explanation. But I am aware of how to answer a question on here. For this type of answer, I feel it is better to show the issue then explain why. IMHO, it is good to give the answerer at least a couple minutes to edit the post. Its not about being first but the structure of the answer. The reason I just put that example is because that **is** the line that is currently causing the error. Then I explain what else needs to happen.

Comment: @codeMagic, I've seen you do this elsewhere as well. First time I downvoted, because I don't see a reason to post an incomplete answer which you can complete within "a couple of minutes" -- if the couple of minutes are worth posting an incomplete answer for, then it would appear that rep points are a consideration.

Comment: @323go.  That does not excuse you from leaving a comment.  With your rep, it's reasonable for the community to expect that.  Now that the answer has been edited, I assume that you will remove the downvote?

Comment: @323go I respect your opinion but a lot of respected members who give great answers do this often. For me, it is easier sometimes to give parts at a time so I can proof each one then all at once to make sure I give a good quality answer at the end

Comment: Besides the fact that at no point was it an incomplete answer. The example I gave and the reason (Spelling) should indicate that it would need to be changed everywhere that is used. I added extra information later just to make it clear and to show how the solution was figured out

Comment: The application now works and shows the first screen but upon transition it shuts down again.

Comment: @codeMagic  Agreed.  Another consideration is that if you take the time to compose the full answer, rep farmers get in with link only answers, incomplete ones or even incorrect ones.  The OP doesn't wait to see what happen and just accepts the first one they think solves the immediate problem.  Putting in placeholders then editing to perfection is a good technique to improve quality.

Comment: @Learning2Code New question please.  No question and answers in comments.

Comment: I added my upvote to Henry's answer, he was first to post a complete answer and should receive credit. If you agree that StackOverflow's goal is to help other programmers and encourage community participation, you will do the same thing.

Comment: @Simon: "rep farmers" = someone who posts an incomplete answer just to "get in", and then fills it out later? I rest my case.

Comment: @Simon well said. Kuddos to you for understanding how SO works. And yes, Learning2Code please post a new question with relevant logcat and most relevant code please

Comment: @Simon: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up -- compare to: "I only upvote to cancel downvotes." You might want to reconsider how you vote.

Comment: @323go Absolutely disagree on rep farmers.  Using your criteria, the people who are prepared to spend time crafting good answers will not get the accepts and votes they deserve and hence will not be encourage to continue that behaviour.  In your shoes, I would have the good grace to reverse the measly -2, but that's just me.  Anyway, off to more productive things now.  Bon chance.

Comment: @323go I really hate to keep this going but re-read what Simon said. That wasn't the only reason he gave

Comment: oh I apologize, I am new here.  Thanks for catching my spelling error though.

Comment: guys, there are lot more questions to be answered here ! :P

Comment: @codeMagic -- my last post on the topic: You might want to re-read what Simon wrote. He's completely mistaken on how votes work, but his mistake is to your benefit.

Comment: @Learning2Code welcome to SO and no problem. The problem with multiple/unrelated questions in a single post is that it gets too confusing for other visitors which could make the answers useless to anyone else. Good luck!

Comment: @Learning2Code  That's OK.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Feel free to ask as many question as you like but I do encourage you to read the FAQ about asking good questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is spelled `TextView` not `Textview` in the XML layout file.